# What is the === (triple-equals) operator in Scala Koans?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala-2.9

I started working my way through the [Scala Koans](http://www.scalakoans.org/), which is organized around a suite of unit tests with blanks that one needs to fill in.  (This idea was modeled after a similar Ruby Koans project.)   You start the sbt tool running a test, and it admonishes:

```
[info]   + ***************************************** 
[info]   +  
[info]   +  
[info]   +  
[info]   + Please meditate on koan "None equals None" of suite "AboutEmptyValues" 
[info]   +  
[info]   +  
[info]   +  
[info]   + *****************************************
```

...and so you go look at this unit test and it says:

```
test("None equals None") {
  assert(None === __)
}
```

...and, after meditation, you realize that you should fill in the blank like this:

```
test("None equals None") {
  assert(None === None)
}
```

...and then it moves on to the next unit test.

My question, though, is what is this `===` operator? I can't seem to find it anywhere.  Is this a DSL operator defined in the Scala Koans project itself?  Or is it part of the ScalaTest framework?  Or in Scala proper?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This is the triple-equals operator from [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/). Have a look at this page: [Getting Started with FunSuite](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite). It says:

> ScalaTest lets you use Scala's assertion syntax, but defines a triple
>   equals operator (===) to give you better error messages. The following
>   code would give you an error indicating only that an assertion failed:
>
> ```
> assert(1 == 2)
> ```
>
> Using triple equals instead would give you the more informative error
>   message, "1 did not equal 2":
>
> ```
> assert(1 === 2)
> ```